# Polyfill for DOM element delete?

Tags: javascript, function, polyfills

I need to create the polyfill for DOM element delete. Can not understand, what is I making wrong. The `deleteElements()` method must delete the current element.

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>

<script>
  if (document.documentElement.deleteElements === undefined) {
    object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'deleteElements', {
        get: function() {
            var elem = this.firstChild;
            delete elem;
            return
        },

        set: function(variable) {
            this.firstChild = variable;
        }

    });
  }

  var elem = document.body.children[0];

  elem.deleteElements(); // <-- call must delete an element

</script>
```

Comment: Check console for errors (there's a plenty of).

Comment: You have a typo: `remov` where you want `remove`. Or `remove` where you want `remov` (as you used `remov` twice but `remove` just once). You need to be consistent.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no, I need exactly `remov`

Comment: Separately: That's not a good polyfill for `remove` (why in heaven's name would you have a getter and setter?). [Here's a better one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).

Comment: @SviatKuzhelev: No, again, you need to be consistent. It's no good testing for `remov`, trying to use `remov`, but defining `remove`.

Comment: That's also not at all how `delete` is used. [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) removes a property from an object. It has nothing to do with removing an element from the DOM.

Comment: And now (as of your edit) you're testing for `deleteElements`, using `deleteElements`, but still defining `remove`.

Comment: Stop trying to use a getter and setter for this and just use an ordinary function. Right now, `elem.deleteElements` would evaluate to `undefined` and trying to call that will produce an error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder now I understand. Thank you. I had change `remove` on `deleteElements` where is needed. But I still do not understand how I can improve the delete Polyfill to make it work.

Comment: @SviatKuzhelev: What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems there:

1. You're defining a property with a getter and setter, then using that property as as function, but the getter doesn't return a function. You almost certainly don't want to use a getter and setter.
2. As I said in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366852/polyfill-for-dom-element-delete?noredirect=1#comment83720288_48366852), `delete` has nothing to do with removing elements from the DOM. [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) removes a property from an object. It has nothing to do with removing an element from the DOM.

If you want to remove the first child of an element without using the native `remove`, you'd do this:

```
this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
```

(There's also no need for `return` at the end of a function unless you're returning a value.)

If you want define a new method on `Element.prototype`, you'd do it like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "deleteElements", {
    value: function() {
        // ...code here...
    },
    writable: true,    // These are the values for the
    enumerable: true,  // `remove` property on `Element.prototype`
    configurable: true // on browsers that property support it
});
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: @SviatKuzhelev: No worries, glad that helped!